# Android Gallery Text Only

Tags: android, gallery

I've looked into the API Demos and they have an example of the gallery where they show just text, the code just uses a Cursor , however I want to use a String array. How can I achieve using it? This is the code for the example in API Demos:

```
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    // Use a template that displays a text view
            android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item,
            // Give the cursor to the list adatper
            c,
            // Map the NAME column in the people database to...
            new String[] {People.NAME},
            // The "text1" view defined in the XML template
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to display a static list of `String` objects, an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) should do:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, new String[] {People.NAME});
```

However, if you want to be able to add more `String` objects to the list later, you should use a `List`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace the `CursorAdapter` with an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).